# Java: file not found exception

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

```
File file1 = new File("news1.txt");
System.out.println(file1.exists());
```

This prints false, but file `news1.txt` is in directory, with that class.

Comment: obviously it is looking to a different folder than you

Comment: how do you run your program?

Comment: try adding the the canonical path of `news1.txt` in here `new File(CANONICAL_PATH)` then check

Comment: The working directory and the classpath are different places.

Comment: I run it from Eclipse, with canonical path it also throw file not found exeption

Comment: So I cut txt file from src directory to root directory, and it works now, thx all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that news1.txt is in the same folder as the class, calling this code. If you are using Eclipse, for example, this will look for the file in the root folder of the project, and not in the src folder. You should verify that the file is indeed in the right location.

Answer (score 0):

I usually fist try to get folder from where my class reads. That's easily done by writing a test file on disc and taking a look where it was created. You can do that with:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("the-file-name.txt", "UTF-8");
writer.println("The first line");
writer.println("The second line");
writer.close();
```

Now you know where your default directory is so you can navigate to your file or put your file in right place